# Highlight listview row on key press

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

I have a dynamic List View. I want to get the list view row hilighted when the user press any key. Suppose, I have Username column in list View. 
For example, we have three list view items:
John 
Michael
Harry

So, when the user press character "J" or "Jo" on keyboard, it should highlight the row that has username John. Similarly it should do for others. Please help me to achieve this.

XAML:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>            
            <GridViewColumn Header="Username">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Username}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach an additional dependency property on each TextBox and bind it to search text value. Once search text changes the property value changed event of each attached property will fire. Inside the handler you will be able to find out if string matches TextBox.Text